# Microsoft Fakes "Assembly not supported"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes

I am attempting to add a Fakes assembly (in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate) for an library that I reference in my code so that I can test independently of the libraries implementation. The the problem I'm having is that when I right click the referenced assembly and click "Add Fakes Assembly" I receive the message:

"Assembly not supported
Fakes does not support this assembly."

I've tried Googling this message but get 0 results if I put it in quotes and nothing relevant if I don't. I thought this was quite strange as you would expect someone else to have run into this issue at some point but anyway...

After giving up on searching for the message I tried searching for somewhere that might tell me what types of assembly Microsoft Fakes does support but this also proved fruitless.

I guess my question is: Does anyone know what types of assembly Microsoft Fakes does/doesn't support.

I've included some information about the assembly I'm referencing in case anyone knows why this one in particular isn't supported:
-Its a COM Interop assembly.
-Its an ActiveX component.
-It isn't strongly named.

Any leads at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio are you running (as in Express/Pro/Ultimate etc..)? According to [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx) only Premium and Ultimate are supported.

Comment: @keyboardP Yes, this matters, even Update version: Premium is only Fakes capable since VS 2012 Update 2 http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2919309-provide-microsoft-fakes-with-all-visual-studio-edi

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746742/fakes-framework-is-not-available-in-vs12-premium

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 with Update 3. It's also worth noting that I can create fakes assemblies for other assemblies, just not this one.

Comment: I don't know then. Fakes can have it's limitations like with certain Generics types and return types. Maybe it's a bug!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the things you mentioned probably aren't the problem. It's entirely possible to fake Excel interop classes, for instance (not that you can use them!).

But if you take a look at what thing's don't support fakes, such as sealed classes, which don't allow stubs because stubs require inheritance, and some reflection classes which restrict shims, it's clear that some classes will have neither, thereby allowing a dll to have no fakeable components. Not much you can do there.

Additionally, `Shims cannot be used on all types from the .NET base class library mscorlib and System.` says [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx#bkmk_limitations).